# GDAL installation on MAC OSX via conda fails, linked due to Libpoppler and font configuration

Tags: python, gdal, conda

When installing GDAL via Conda, install fails, on OSX Mojave and Python 3.7:

```
dlopen(/Users/tomkom/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/osgeo/_gdal.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libfontconfig.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/tomkom/anaconda3/lib/libpoppler.78.dylib
  Reason: Incompatible library version: libpoppler.78.dylib requires version 14.0.0 or later, but libfontconfig.1.dylib provides version 13.0.0
```

I am unable to locate the cause. Installed using:

```
 conda install -c conda-forge gdal
```

As per standard.

The error seems to indicate issues with libpoppler and a font library (libfontconfig). I am unsure about the role of these libraries and how to update them.

Comment: i recommend installing your gis stack into a new environment: e.g., `conda create --name=gis python=3.6 gdal geopandas rasterio ipykernel --channel=conda-forge`

Comment: @PaulH Any suggestion why forcing python to a lower version? Mine is 3.7. I would need to install an older one... Also, why ipykernel?

Comment: Lower version: I'm not sure e.g. geopandas and rasterio are available on python 3.7 yet. Even if they are available for Python 3.7, since so much of the GIS stack is written in C, compiled, and linked together, it's definitely better to install everything at the same time, and from a single channel (I prefer conda-forge).

You need the ipykernel to let the environment talk to whatever jupyer notebook or jupyter lab server you have running, if you have one running, which I recommend you do.

Comment: I just did a quick `conda search` for gdal and geopandas and python 3.7 builds are available. pick which ever python you want, but use a fresh environment in either case.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. A clean environment helped with a different downstream issue, yet standalone GDAL still has issues with the fonts. This is what I am waiting for as an answer - clarification why fonts should be a problem, how to resolve this issue, and why this happens now on Mojave, not before.

Comment: You should edit your question to clarify as it's not at all clear that fonts are the issue.

Comment: I do not "know" whether fonts are an issue, but the errors noted relate to font libraries. Hence, this is not a standard "how to install gdal with conda" question, but one seeking answer to that particular error. I will update the wording.

Answer (score 2):

Got this error too when all my GIS related packages (geopandas, gdal, fiona) that all seem to rely on that libfontconfig randomnly broke.

In terminal, I had to first install the fontconfig package using brew

```
brew install fontconfig
```

Navigate to your python install path, which is in your error:

```
cd /Users/tomkom/anaconda3/lib/
```

Rename the libfontconfig to a backup version

```
mv libfontconfig.1.dylib libfontconfig.1.dylib.bak
```

Create a symbolic link from your python library to where the fontconfig library is installed in step 1

```
ln -s /usr/local/lib/libfontconfig.1.dylib .
```

Check your python version of libfontconfig is now up to date

```
otool -L libfontconfig.1.dylib
```

Mine says `/usr/local/opt/fontconfig/lib/libfontconfig.1.dylib (compatibility version 14.0.0, current version 14.0.0)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It resolve my issue, too.